# How do I disable the missed phone call notification light?

Tags: calls, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9

The green flashing light whenever I miss a call is really annoying.  I'd like to turn that off while keeping the purplish voicemail indicator light.  I'm not finding a clear way to do it in the phone app nor in general settings.  The similar questions I've seen have actually been about the call log or other notifications which are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible to change it in setting(you can only completly turn it off or on). But you have some apps for that. For most of them,you need root. But I found this one in link(article about it) for which you do not need it. It is Led Blinker(avaiable in Google Play Store)You have lite and pro version, but lite should be more than enought.

LINK WITH INSTRUCTIONS HOW TO USE IT: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.guidingtech.com/23212/customize-disable-led-notifications-android/&ved=2ahUKEwig0IfSvvbjAhVG2KQKHSndB48QFjASegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3YIcmp9EWQpzvCGuaCwlLU&cshid=1565378157374

Comment: OK, how can I turn it off completely in settings?

Comment: Hello. Can you link instructions from that link right here into the answer? Links having instructions/usage are terrible to rely upon as they can expire anytime thus robbing the usefulness of a link-dependent answer.

Comment: Link is just annex to answer and it is not important for question.

Comment: you need to go into  settings > accessibility > Hearing > Flash Alerts - and turn it off.